# Google api login gives Error 500 in Webview

Tags: android, webview, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am using `WebView` in my app for google login.

```
private static final String SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN             = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
private static final String SCOPE_PLUS_USER_INFO_EMAIL   = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
private static final String SCOPE_PLUS_USER_INFO_PROFILE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";

void loadUrl() {
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=" + SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN + "+" + SCOPE_PLUS_USER_INFO_EMAIL + "+" + SCOPE_PLUS_USER_INFO_PROFILE + "&redirect_uri=" + GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL + "&response_type=code&client_id=" + GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;);
}
```

First login works fine, I typed email, password, google show scopes permissions. But on the second login I got 500 error on url like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&response_type=code&redirect_uri=my_redirect_url&client_id=my_client_id&hl=uk&from_login=1&as=478a8e5eead4aff6
```

[image: screenshot]

What reason of such behavior? I checked `client_id` and redirect url - they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get new access token because your old one has not expired yet.
You must get the access token ONCE, save it somewhere and use it until it expires, you can not get new access token each time you try to query something

to revoke your first access token [go to Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and you will find it under Client ID for installed applications

Comment: Is it possible approach to programatically revoke token each time ,before login any user?

Comment: I don't think so, as the time limit is set by Google itself.